# XML parsing error without visable mistake [help!]

Tags: android, xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen android:title="Settings"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:kik="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/kik.android">
<kik.android.widget.preferences.BrickPref android:enable="true" android:title="iOSrekt" android:key="kik.ios.exploit" android:summary="Bricks iOS kik accounts with a message (for older kik versions)" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I cut out the majority of the code that I know for sure works, and left the base xml. Any clues? /:

Comment: What is the exact problem?

Comment: I'm allergical to the words `iOS`, `exploit` and to **malware** in genre. Which the sentence `Bricks iOS kik accounts ...` explicitly alludes.

Comment: @ThomasR. line 5 shows an error with every debugger I use, yet I cannot find what to change. Here is the error message from XMLspy: File F:\spookik\res\xml\preferences_spookik.xml is not valid.
 Character '<' within text '<kik.android.wid' does not fulfill production 'Name'.
  Details
   XML Production Error: Character '<' within text '<kik.android.wid' does not fulfill production 'Name'.

Answer (score 1):

You must include layout_width and layout_height attributes to the PreferenceScreen node

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="Settings"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```